# Entity Framework Core async update fails with 0 affected row

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following insert and update code in a Xamarin mobile project:

```
public async Task SaveData(T data, bool update)
{
  try
  {
    if (update)
      dbContext.Set<T>().Attach(data);
    else
      await dbContext.Set<T>().AddAsync(data);
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    Log();
    throw;
  }
}
```

When I *update* an existing record, I always get an exception:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException (System.Int32 commandIndex, System.Int32 expectedRowsAffected, System.Int32 rowsAffected) [0x0001e] in <e12f0cc891a249419803faaf433b12e6>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch+<ConsumeResultSetWithoutPropagationAsync>d__6.MoveNext () [0x000e9] in <e12f0cc891a249419803faaf433b12e6>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch+<ConsumeAsync>d__2.MoveNext () [0x0016f] in <e12f0cc891a249419803faaf433b12e6>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch+<ExecuteAsync>d__32.MoveNext () [0x00142] in <e12f0cc891a249419803faaf433b12e6>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__10.MoveNext () [0x00220] in <e12f0cc891a249419803faaf433b12e6>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager+<SaveChangesAsync>d__79.MoveNext () [0x00088] in <159bf28779664ac6914c3caf595e15c9>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager+<SaveChangesAsync>d__77.MoveNext () [0x000f8] in <159bf28779664ac6914c3caf595e15c9>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext+<SaveChangesAsync>d__52.MoveNext () [0x000cf] in <159bf28779664ac6914c3caf595e15c9>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at MyXamarin.DatabaseProject.Repository.SaveData [0x0036f]
```

This is what I can see in the Entity Framework Core log:

```
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking[10801]
      DetectChanges completed for 'MyContext'.
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20000]
      Opening connection to database 'main' on server '/data/data/com.example.MyXamarinProject/files/XamarinDB.db'.
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20001]
      Opened connection to database 'main' on server '/data/data/com.example.MyXamarinProject/files/XamarinDB.db'.
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction[20200]
      Beginning transaction with isolation level 'Serializable'.
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@p1='3201a98f-36b2-4b8c-87d2-4f7f85221b28' (DbType = String), @p0='55' (Size = 2)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      UPDATE "Detail" SET "Level" = @p0
      WHERE "DetailID" = @p1;
      SELECT changes();
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[@p1='3201a98f-36b2-4b8c-87d2-4f7f85221b28' (DbType = String), @p0='55' (Size = 2)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      UPDATE "Detail" SET "Level" = @p0
      WHERE "DetailID" = @p1;
      SELECT changes();
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20300]
      A data reader was disposed.
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction[20204]
      Disposing transaction.
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20002]
      Closing connection to database 'main' on server '/data/data/com.example.MyXamarinProject/files/XamarinDB.db'.
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20003]
      Closed connection to database 'main' on server '/data/data/com.example.MyXamarinProject/files/XamarinDB.db'.
[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'MyXamarinProject.Database.MyContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
```

According to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/ef/core/saving/concurrency) in the error message, it might be some concurrency problem.

I modified the code based on that article to check if the entity exists in the database:

```
public async Task SaveData(T data, bool update)
{
  try
  {
    if (update)
      dbContext.Set<T>().Attach(data);
    else
      await dbContext.Set<T>().AddAsync(data);
    var dbValue = GetFromDb<Detail>(b => b.DetailID == Guid.Parse("3201a98f-36b2-4b8c-87d2-4f7f85221b28")); //dbValue does exist!!!
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
  }
  catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException dbex)
  {
    foreach (var entry in dbex.Entries)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(entry.State); //it is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified
      if (entry.Entity is Detail)
      {
        var proposedValues = entry.CurrentValues;
        var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues(); //IT IS ALWAYS NULL!!!

        foreach (var property in proposedValues.Properties)
        {
          var proposedValue = proposedValues[property];
          var databaseValue = databaseValues[property];

          // TODO: decide which value should be written to database
          // proposedValues[property] = <value to be saved>;
        }

        // Refresh original values to bypass next concurrency check
        entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
      }
      else
      {
        throw new NotSupportedException(
            "Don't know how to handle concurrency conflicts for "
            + entry.Metadata.Name);
      }
    }
  }
```

It seems that somehow the real database is 'lost' along the way, as `GetDatabaseValues()` suggests.

What should I do?

***Bonus***: when I try to add a new entity, I always get a foreign key problem as if the entites that are referenced by the navigation properties are not existing.

**UPDATE**

When I use `NoTracking` to get the entities from the database, during the save it tries to insert a new entity that is a *navigation property* inside another entity that is a navigation property of `Detail`. Why does Entity Framework feel the need to insert a completely new entity if a navigation property is null?

**UPDATE 2**

It looks like some serious bug in Entity Framework Core.

If I run the following line, I get every entity:

```
var full = await dbContext.Detail.ToListAsync();
```

If I run the following line, I get the entity I intend to update:

```
var fullFilter = full.Where(b => b.DetailID == data.DetalID).FirstOrDefault();
```

If I run the following line, I get 0 entity:

```
var actual = dbContext.Detail.Where(b => b.DetailID == data.DetalID).FirstOrDefault();
```

I guess the latter is what  Entity Framework Core uses internally...

What is the difference?

Comment: Looks like there's no row in the database for the entity, thus the failed update and the output of GetDatabaseValues().  So you need to insert, but your question is vague on what is failing when you try that.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I _read_ the entities _from the database_, I select one of them and when I save the entity read from the database, I get the exception. How can I read them from the database, if the row is not existing?

Comment: That shouldn't happen, unless the row was deleted between your SELECT and UPDATE.  So can you produce and post in your question a repro? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It is not that easy to create a project of this type, the data is sensitive. Can I somehow be sure about that the data is still there?

Comment: "Can I somehow be sure about that the data is still there?"  You can monitor the database.  For SQL Server you could use Trace or Extended Events.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The database is an SQLite file on a device. I don't think I can use those tools. Entity Framework Core log should do that.

Comment: Not sure.  Can you simply examine the database?  Perhaps getting a case-sensitivity comparison mismatch when trying to match the GUID, as you appear to be sending this as a string parameter?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Now I have access to a downloaded version of the database. It contains the row in question. Why can't it be found on update when the entity tracker contains it? Also, the string key was only a test to find the entity in the database, the search is executed by the context during save.